# How do I stop the marker size from changing location point in Scattergeo?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to set a bubble map with go.scattergeo, everything is good so far but when I change the size of the bubbles (each one represents a number), the biggest one "absorbs" the smallest one, see pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgnIG.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5IrD.png

As you can see I have commented out two more options that I tried, but both ended with the same result. Changing the color doesn't affect the position, and I've checked the whole documentation and found nothing about it.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

This is my code so far

This is a 10 row sample of the DF i'm using (essentially it's the titanic database with assigned latitude and longitude for each port of departure):

PassengerId Survived    Pclass  Name    Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Ticket  Fare    Embarked    lon lat 0   1   0   3   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris 0   22.000000   1   0   A/5 21171   7.2500  0   -1.406013   50.896364 1 2   1   1   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...   1   38.000000   1   0   PC 17599    71.2833 1   -8.294143   51.850910 2 3   1   3   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  1   26.000000   0   0   STON/O2. 3101282    7.9250  0   -1.406013   50.896364 3 4   1   1   Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)    1   35.000000   1   0   113803  53.1000 0   -1.406013   50.896364 4 5   0   3   Allen, Mr. William Henry    0   35.000000   0   0   373450  8.0500  0   -1.406013   50.896364 5 6   0   3   Moran, Mr. James    0   29.699118   0   0   330877  8.4583  2   -1.612260   49.648194 6 7   0   1   McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J 0   54.000000   0   0   17463   51.8625 0   -1.406013   50.896364 7 8   0   3   Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard  0   2.000000    3   1   349909  21.0750 0   -1.406013   50.896364 8 9   1   3   Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)   1   27.000000   0   2   347742  11.1333 0   -1.406013   50.896364 9 10  1   2   Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem) 1   14.000000   1   0   237736  30.0708 1   -8.294143   51.850910

Basically it's titanic dataset with coordenates assigned to each port of departure as it follows:

```
df.replace({'Embarked':{'S':0, 'C':1, 'Q':2}}, inplace=True)
df.loc[df['Embarked']==0, 'lon'] = '-1.406013'
df.loc[df['Embarked']==1, 'lon'] = '-8.294143'
df.loc[df['Embarked']==2, 'lon'] = '-1.612260'

df.loc[df['Embarked']==0, 'lat'] = '50.896364'
df.loc[df['Embarked']==1, 'lat'] = '51.850910'
df.loc[df['Embarked']==2, 'lat'] = '49.648194'
```

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go


sizearray = np.asarray(df['lon'].value_counts())

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(lon = df['lon'],lat = df['lat'],mode = 'markers'))

fig.update_layout(
        title = 'Shipping Ports',geo_scope='world',)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations") 
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=sizearray,sizemode='area',sizeref=2.*max(sizearray)/(40.**2),sizemin=4))
#fig.update_traces(marker_size=sizearray/5)
#fig.update_traces(marker_size=df['lon'].value_counts()/5)
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(color=['rgb(93, 164, 214)', 'rgb(255, 144, 14)','rgb(44, 160, 101)']))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide reproducible sample data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to visualize the number of people embarking from each port, you can either draw a graph with a data frame grouping the original data, or you can create a graph based on unique values of latitude and longitude, similar to the way the number of cases was extracted. I have obtained the latitude and longitude as well as the array of counts and specified it as the latitude and longitude. I also customized the marker size and coloring with your code. Please correct me if my customization is wrong.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

sizearray = np.asarray(df['lon'].value_counts())
latarray = np.asarray(df['lat'].unique())
lonarray = np.asarray(df['lon'].unique())

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(lon=lonarray,
                                   lat=latarray,
                                   mode='markers',
                                   marker=dict(
                                       size=sizearray,
                                       sizemode='area',
                                       sizeref=2.*max(sizearray)/(40.**2),
                                       sizemin=4,
                                       color=[
                                           'rgb(93, 164, 214)',
                                           'rgb(255, 144, 14)',
                                           'rgb(44, 160, 101)'
                                       ]
                                   )))

fig.update_layout(autosize=True, height=600, title='Shipping Ports', geo_scope='europe')
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations") 
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much. I still wonder what is wrong with my code and why it puts the green marker inside the blue one, would you happen to know why?

Comment: The scatterplot on the map depicts 3 points with 10 data points. I assume that you then updated the color and size of the markers at some point in those three locations.